# KDE/Plasma OSD message doesn't disappear automatically

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde, notify-osd

I'm using Kubuntu 15.04. See the screenshot for the exact version.

The on screen display (OSD) message "System Update Available" doesn't disappear automatically. It stays forever on the screen, but other OSD messages disappear automatically after some seconds.

My workaround is to do:

```
killall notify-osd
```

in a terminal. This command removes the OSD message. Do you know a bug fix or another solution for this problem?

Update: The OSD message disappears after some interaction with the package management e.g. if I update all packages. So maybe this is a feature to force me to update my system?

[image: screenhot]

Comment: @DavidCole Please don't remove the screenshots from the questions, it's better / easier to have them directly in the question's body.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug (I was very annoyed too), and it [looks to be resolved in Plasma 5.3](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340068). You are using 5.2. So I whould update to latest Plasma via backports.

Or, if you can wait a bit longer, and want to stay "official": 15.10 release is imminent (end of October) and it will feature Plasma 5.4.

To install Plasma 5.3, you can use this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports